# How to run for loop in java?

Tags: java

I would like to know why this code do not run. Is there something missing?

Count the number of `"xx"` in the given string. We'll say that overlapping is allowed, so `"xxx"` contains 2 `"xx"`.

```
public class Drumkit {
    int countXX(String str){
        String a = "abcxxx";
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (a.substring(i, i + 2).equals("xx")) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: check str value

Comment: What do you mean when you say the code doesn't run? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: simple debugging will give you the answer to your question

Comment: Your for loop goes from 0 to `str.length()-1`, but within the for loop you check the contents of `a`

Comment: you should call countXX method through main method @Chasuna

Comment: Please correct your method to 

private static int countXX(String str){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("xx")) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `str` and using its `length()` in your function. But, in the loop you're using `a` (local string variable) which seems like a logical mistake.

You need to pass the input string when your call this function and use `str` (the function argument) to count the matches.

Here's a functional example:

```
class Test
{
    static int countXX( final String str ) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("xx")) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final String s = "abcxxx";
        final int count = countXX( s );
        System.out.println( count );
    }
}
```

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/Lm6Ir4

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unclear. however, you can try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int count = countXX("abcxx efjxx xyzxx xx xxxx xx","xx");
    System.out.println(count);
}

static int countXX(final String text, final String occurrenceOf){
    int count = 0;
    int fromIndex=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 1; i++) {
        int index = text.indexOf(occurrenceOf,fromIndex);
        if(index >-1) {
            count++;
            fromIndex=index+1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```